# php mysql insert not working when including specific text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> "Autism is a disorder of neural development characterized by impaired social interaction and communication, and by restricted and repetitive behavior. The diagnostic criteria require that symptoms become apparent before a child is three years old. Autism affects information processing in the brain by altering how nerve cells and their synapses connect and organize; how this occurs is not well understood."@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> "Anarchism is generally defined as the political philosophy which holds the state to be undesirable, unnecessary, and harmful, or alternatively as opposing authority and hierarchical organization in the conduct of human relations. Proponents of anarchism, known as \"anarchists\", advocate stateless societies based on non-hierarchical voluntary associations. There are many types and traditions of anarchism, not all of which are mutually exclusive."@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Achilles> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment> "In Greek mythology, Achilles was a Greek hero of the Trojan War, the central character and the greatest warrior of Homer's Iliad. Plato named Achilles the most handsome of the heroes assembled against Troy. Later legends (beginning with a poem by Statius in the 1st century AD) state that Achilles was invulnerable in all of his body except for his heel. As he died because of a small wound on his heel, the term Achilles' heel has come to mean a person's principal weakness."@en .
```

I'm using code (not relevant here) to extract the name of the article in the first url in each line. Then I extract the first sentence of the description between quotes. The problem is when I try to insert that first sentence string into my table, the insert fails (echoing works fine). Just inserting the title without the description works fine. Does anyone have any idea why the description makes the insert fail?

Here's the code I'm using to get the first sentence:

```
 $data = fgets($handle); //get line

 $data = str_replace("> ", "-!-", $data);

 dataArr = explode("-!-", $data);

 //Get last part of uri from 1st element in array
  $title = getLastPartOfUrl($dataArr[0]);   
  $desc=preg_replace('/(.*?[?!.](?=\s|$)).*/', '\\1', escape(substr($dataArr[2],1)));

  $db->query("insert into mytable SET title = '".$title."', desc ='".$desc."'");

  function escape($str)
    {
            $search=array("\\","\0","\n","\r","\x1a","'",'"');
            $replace=array("\\\\","\\0","\\n","\\r","\Z","\'",'\"');
            return str_replace($search,$replace,$str);
    }
```

EDIT: I tried both urlencode and addslashes to no avail, in both cases including the $desc string makes the insert fail.

Comment: Why use this weird escape function instead of the proper one provided by whichever library you are using?

Comment: "function escape()` o_O

Comment: Are you sure your escaping is good? I don't know if in your case is this usefull, but what about trying php method url encode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I tried both urlencode and addslashes instead of the escape function, neither one helped... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't escape the `title`.

I wouldn't trust your `escape` function either.  I'm not sure what `$db` is, but you should use properly parameterized queries with PDO/mysqli

EDIT: `DESC` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You need to surround it (when used as a column name) with backticks in your query.

Comment: The title variable isn't the problem, as long as I leave out $desc the titles insert fine. I also tried urlencode and addslashes instead of the escape function, neither one worked...

Comment: @Phil what DB library are you using?

Comment: Explosion Pills, excuse the newbie question, but what do you mean by "DB library"?

Comment: @Phil are you using PDO, mysqli, or `mysql_*`?

Comment: Mysql (planning on upgrading to mysqli, but didn't get around to it yet)

Comment: @Phil in that case use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `escape`

Comment: I just tried     " $desc=mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('/(.*?[?!.](?=\s|$)).*/', '\\1', substr($dataArr[2],1)));" , didn't work...I feel like I'm going insane!

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace`?

Comment: To extract the first sentence from the longer description on each line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25105/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-phil)

Comment: Desc was the problem. I changed the column name, and everything works great!